# How to put Convert.ToInt32 in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, type-conversion, sql-order-by

I need a lambda expression with the `Convert.ToInt32()` method to be used in the `Queryable.OrderBy(query, lambdaExpression)` method.

I did something like this but it doesn't work properly :/

```
private static LambdaExpression ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
        {
            var modelParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            Expression body = modelParameter;
            UnaryExpression? bodyAsInt = null;
            foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
            {
                body = Expression.PropertyOrField(modelParameter, member);

                bodyAsInt = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(Int32));
            }

            return Expression.Lambda(bodyAsInt, modelParameter);
        }
```

Usage as follows:
`Queryable.OrderBy(source, ToLambda<T>(SortParameter.ParameterName))`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why? Is this supposed to be translated to SQL, such as with Entity Framework?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `OrderBy` works with lambdas anyway. It's already dynamic - it can work with any *expression* lambda. You can add any `OrderBy` you want to any `IQueryable<>` query.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, EF translates the `OrderBy (x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Property)` code.
I need this because one of the columns in my DB is of the string type and I want to sort it as int and do it in a ready sorting mechanism

Comment: If you want to create "dynamic" LINQ, you should probably think more about what you try to do. It's quite likely you need a SQL query builder, not LINQ. LINQ is used to avoid writing queries as strings. A LINQ query gets translated to SQL. What you try to do is take a string query, create an Expression and LINQ query that will eventually create *another* string query.

Comment: @EmilOS why do you want this? This is guaranteed to cause bad performance. That `int.Parse(x.Property)` will get translated to a function that prevents the use of any indexes. Whether it's translated to `cast(Property as int)` or `CONVERT(...)`, any index that covers that property will be built using the *text* values, not the numeric values. What you try to do could end up scanning an entire table or forcing the server to spool all results into a temporary table so it can sort them on the fly

Comment: `one of the columns in my DB is of the string type` why not convert it to a numeric type then? If you really need both forms and you run this query frequently you could create a computed persisted column with `CAST(Property as int)` and index it. Even if you really want to use LINQ, why not use `.OrderBy(x=>x.Property)` ? Why go through a string?

Comment: I have created a dynamic sort for multiple sort parameters. I also have an OrderBy<T> extension method and I use lambda expression there, but I also have one column with a string type that I want to sort as int and I cannot change the type in the database. So I want to put the type conversion in here somewhere